# how to stream a mp3 audio from firebase storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I'm developing an app that will stream mp3 file stored in firebase storage. Nearly I'm having 100 songs like song1,song2,song3..... if a song is selected I have to stream that particular song without downloading. In such case I need to write plenty of code because for each song I have to mention the firebase storage url. the url would be like

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/......song1.mp3?alt=media&token=8a8a0593-e8bb-40c7-87e0-814d9c8342f3
```

For each song the **alt=media&token=** part of the url varies, so I have to mention the unique url for all songs. But here I need some simplified coding to play the songs by mentioning its name alone from firebase storage.

Please suggest a way to stream the audio file by using its name alone that is stored in firebase storage.

Comment: what language are you writing your app in?

Answer (score 9):

You have two choices if you want to get files out of a Firebase Storage bucket.

1. Use the full download url that you can get from a Storage Reference that points to the file path in your bucket.
2. Use a download task (Android or iOS) to fetch the data from the file.

You can't get the file data any other way from within a mobile app.  Firebase Storage doesn't support special media streaming protocols, such as RTSP.

Answer (score 4):

I did it using `downloadUrl`.

```
val storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
storage.reference.child("songs/song1.mp3").downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener({
    val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(it.toString())
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener { player ->
        player.start()
    }
    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StorageReference filepath=storage.child("Audio").child(timeStamp+".mp3");
        Uri uri=Uri.fromFile(new File(fileName));
        filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                String audio_url=taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();
```

Use `audio_url`to stream the audio file using media player

Comment: is it a javascript used in browsers? or is it a android application?